# More than one datapool to a script in RFT

Tags: testing, automated-tests, rft

Is there any way can we add two datapools to a single script? Or in other words how can we get inputs from two different datapools to a single script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can manually load and manage any number of datapools.

```
    /**
 * Creates a IDatapoolIterator pointing the first record
 * @param datastore default project path
 * @param dataPoolPath relative path in the project
 * @return IDatapoolIterator pointing the first record
 */
public static IDatapoolIterator getDataPoolIterator(String datastore, String dataPoolPath)
{
    java.io.File dpFile = new java.io.File(datastore, dataPoolPath+".rftdp");

    DatapoolScriptSupport dss = new DatapoolScriptSupport();

    IDatapool dp = (IDatapool) dss.dpFactory().load(dpFile, true);
    IDatapoolIterator dpIter = dss.dpFactory().open(dp, null);

    dpIter.dpInitialize(dp);
    dpIter.dpReset();

    return dpIter;
}
```

then in your code

```
myDatapool = getDataPoolIterator((String)getOption(IOptionName.DATASTORE), "relative/path/intheproject");
```

You can access any Variable in the datapool by

```
myDatapool.dpString("Variable");
```

Use the correct method depending the type of the variable you need. Using

```
myDatapool.dpNext();
```

you will advance to the next record in the datapool.
Hope this will help.
Further informations here: [IBM Help System: Datapool](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.rational.test.ft.api.help/ApiReference/com/rational/test/ft/rational_ft.html)

Comment: Will the above snippets works for accessing datapools which is not associated with the script??

Comment: Yes, you can load any datapool you want as long it resides in the project path:

Comment: Yes its working fine... actually i did a mistake with the path.. thnx for the help.....

Comment: you have to mark this question as answered, if it really helped you solve your problem.