# Storing results in multiple datapools in RFT

Tags: automation, automated-tests, rft

I'm in the middle of an RFT project where I'm going to need to read data from an existing test datapool (associated with the script), then write data to a separate results datapool, so I will need to be able to access both datapools from the same script.

I've found the post below (many thanks to poster), which works fine for reading data from multiple datapools, but doesn't cover writing to them:

[More than one datapool to a script in RFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532061/more-than-one-datapool-to-a-script-in-rft/8701283#8701283)

Would there be any way of modifying this to enable commands similar to setDatapool and storeDatapool, working on a second datapool not associated with the script?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[Programmatically Modifying Rational Datapools](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/programmatically-modify-rational-datapools/) and see the section for Rational Functional Tester.